# Select field based on value in same record

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I want to `SELECT` a field based on a `ID` value.

```
Products
    PRODUCT_ID    Name
    19            Chair
    20            Table

Product_fields
    ID    PRODUCT_ID    TYPE    DESCRIPTION
    1     19            C       White
    2     19            S       Modern
    3     20            C       Black
    4     20            S       Classic
```

I need a result like:

```
Product     Type_C   Type_S
Chair       White    Modern
Table       Black    Classic
```

I am able to produce this using two `LEFT JOINs` on the product_fields table but this slows down the query too much. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can I assume from your wanting to use `LEFT JOIN`s, that you want records for all the rows in `Products`?

Comment: Also, can I assume that each `product_id` in `product_fields` will have both a record with type `C` and with type `S`?

Comment: Can you please show us the latest version of your query and possibly the list of the indexes on the tables?

Comment: If properly keyed the joins should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Slows down the query how much? What is acceptable?

If you really don't want to use joins (you must have one join), then use views or nested queries. But I don't think they will be any faster, though you can give it a try.

See views at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b68f/3)

```
select  p.PRODUCT_ID, p.Name, f.CDescription, f.SDescription
from    Products p
join(
    SELECT  PRODUCT_ID, Max( CDescription ) as CDescription,
            Max( SDescription ) as SDescription
    FROM(
        select  PRODUCT_ID,
                case Type when 'C' then Description end as CDescription,
                case Type when 'S' then Description end as SDescription
        from    Fields
      ) x
    group by PRODUCT_ID
) f
on  f.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete statement is:

```
SELECT 
    NL.product_name,
    PRD.product_sku AS product_sku,
    CF.virtuemart_product_id AS virtuemart_product_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct CFA.customsforall_value_name
        ORDER BY CFA.customsforall_value_name ASC
        separator  ' | ' ) AS Name_exp_3,
    ROUND((((prices.product_price * CALC.calc_value) / 100) + prices.product_price),
            2) AS Prijs,
    VMCF_L.custom_value AS latijn,
    VMCF_T.custom_value AS THT
    VMCF_B.custom_value AS Batch
from j25_virtuemart_products AS PRD 
    LEFT join j25_virtuemart_product_custom_plg_customsforall AS CF     ON CF.virtuemart_product_id = PRD.virtuemart_product_id
    join j25_virtuemart_product_prices AS prices                ON PRD.virtuemart_product_id = prices.virtuemart_product_id
    join j25_virtuemart_calcs AS CALC                           ON prices.product_tax_id = CALC.virtuemart_calc_id
    join j25_virtuemart_products_nl_nl AS NL                    ON NL.virtuemart_product_id = PRD.virtuemart_product_id
    LEFT join j25_virtuemart_product_customfields AS VMCF           ON VMCF.virtuemart_product_id = PRD.virtuemart_product_id
    LEFT join j25_virtuemart_custom_plg_customsforall_values AS CFA     ON CFA.customsforall_value_id = CF.customsforall_value_id
    LEFT JOIN j25_virtuemart_product_customfields AS VMCF_L ON VMCF.virtuemart_product_id = VMCF_L.virtuemart_product_id AND VMCF_L.virtuemart_custom_id = 16
    LEFT JOIN j25_virtuemart_product_customfields AS VMCF_T ON VMCF.virtuemart_product_id = VMCF_T.virtuemart_product_id AND VMCF_T.virtuemart_custom_id = 3
    LEFT JOIN j25_virtuemart_product_customfields AS VMCF_B ON VMCF.virtuemart_product_id = VMCF_B.virtuemart_product_id AND VMCF_B.virtuemart_custom_id = 18
WHERE
    PRD.product_sku like '02.%'
group by PRD.virtuemart_product_id
order by NL.product_name;
```

Where the three SELECT results named 'Latijn', 'THT', and 'Batch' are the ones which I compared earlier as the black/white and  classic/modern values.
Hope this makes any sense.
As you can see this involves a Virtuemart installation, so I cannot fiddle about to much with the schema.

When I exclude the bottom 3 JOINS and there related FIELDS, the query takes approx 0,5 seconds. With the JOINS and FIELDS included, the query takes almost 19 seconds.

I have created a view from this complete query which I query from my labeling application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! With your input I created:
`select` 
NL`.`product_name`AS`product_name`,`
PRD`.`product_sku`AS`product_sku`,`
CF`.`virtuemart_product_id`AS`virtuemart_product_id`,
        group_concat(distinct`CFA`.`customsforall_value_name
            `order by`CFA`.`customsforall_value_name`ASC
            separator ' | ') AS`Name_exp_3`,
        round((((`prices`.`product_price`*`CALC`.`calc_value`) / 100) +`prices`.`product_price`),
                2) AS`Prijs`,`
f`.`Latijn`AS`Latijn`,`
f`.`THT`AS`THT`,`
f`.`Batch`AS`Batch
    `from
        (((((((`j25_virtuemart_productsPRD
        `left join`j25_virtuemart_product_custom_plg_customsforallCF`ON ((`CF`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`PRD`.`virtuemart_product_id`)))
        join`j25_virtuemart_product_pricesprices`ON ((`PRD`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`prices`.`virtuemart_product_id`)))
        join`j25_virtuemart_calcsCALC`ON ((`prices`.`product_tax_id`=`CALC`.`virtuemart_calc_id`)))
        join`j25_virtuemart_products_nl_nlNL`ON ((`NL`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`PRD`.`virtuemart_product_id`)))
        left join`j25_virtuemart_product_customfieldsVMCF`ON ((`VMCF`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`PRD`.`virtuemart_product_id`)))
        left join`j25_virtuemart_custom_plg_customsforall_valuesCFA`ON ((`CFA`.`customsforall_value_id`=`CF`.`customsforall_value_id`)))
        left join`vw_batch_Latijn_THT_groupedf`ON ((`f`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`PRD`.`virtuemart_product_id`)))
    where
        (`PRD`.`product_sku`like '02.%')
    group by`PRD`.`virtuemart_product_id
    `order by`NL`.`product_name``

Which takes 1.4 seconds to execute, a whole lot faster then the 19 seconds I started with.